# System.Net.HTTPWebRequest gives an empty response when server responds with 404

Tags: powershell

I have the following code:

```
$r = [System.Net.HTTPWebRequest]::Create("$url")
$resp = $r.GetResponse()
$reqstream = $resp.GetResponseStream()
$sr = new-object System.IO.StreamReader $reqstream
$result = $sr.ReadToEnd()
write-host $result
```

What the web service does is you send a value to it, it checks the value against a database and returns a json object if it finds the value. If it does not find the value, it returns a json object too but this time with a 404 http status code.

The code works if the value is found in the database and can read the response. But if the value is not found, powershell throws an exception and the response is empty. I tried catching the exception and accessing the response within the exception object, but it is also empty:

```
try
{
    $r = [System.Net.HTTPWebRequest]::Create("$url")
    $resp = $r.GetResponse()
    $reqstream = $resp.GetResponseStream()
    $sr = new-object System.IO.StreamReader $reqstream
    $result = $sr.ReadToEnd()
    write-host $result
} 
catch 
{
    $_.Exception.Response
}
```

Is there any way to get the original response when the response code is 404? Please note that I can't use invoke-restmethod or invoke-webrequest.

Response headers taken from Firefox:

[image]

Response json:

[image]

Comment: Could you post the web service code where you are creating the response?

Comment: I can't, but I provided the response headers.